# varibale "count" won't be incremented even though if statement ,to increment it, matches the condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make it so that it chooses the max value in a list that contains all the count variables...you'll see what I mean below.

```
import string

def solve(s):
    assigned_alphabet = {string.ascii_lowercase[num] : num + 1 for num in range(26)}
    non_vowels = "".join([char if char not in "aeiou" else " " for char in s]).split()
    count_list = []
    for item in non_vowels:
        count = 0
        if len(item) > 1:
            for char in item:
                count += assigned_alphabet[char]
            count_list.append(count)
        elif len(item) == 1:
            count += assigned_alphabet[item]
    return max(count_list)
```

It passed the following tests:

```
Test.assert_equals(solve("chruschtschov"),80)
Test.assert_equals(solve("khrushchev"),38)
Test.assert_equals(solve("strength"),57)
Test.assert_equals(solve("catchphrase"),73)
Test.assert_equals(solve("twelfthstreet"),103)
Test.assert_equals(solve("mischtschenkoana"),80)
```

but for some reason failed this one:

```
Test.assert_equals(solve("zodiac"),26)
```

It might be a stupid error, my eyes are tired and I just can't find how I can fix this.

Comment: I don't get it, what's your program supposed to do?

Comment: @Danii Basically what it does is max([a list that contains the count variable for each string in the non_vowels list]) --> e.g "strength" when passed into the function the `non_vowels` variable would be equal to `["str", "ngth" ]`, then the dictionary that contains `{"a" : 1, "b" : 2 and so on}` would make `"str"` == 57 and it does the same patter with the `"ngth"` and then chooses the `max()` of the two which are stored in the `count_list`

Comment: I don't understand either, could you add more documentation to the code? Maybe both a better explanation of the function and some comments explaining the more important lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're program is trying to do, but I see the error.

This line:

```
non_vowels = "".join([char if char not in "aeiou" else " " for char in s]).split()
```

Splits input strings into a list of strings containing non vowels in between the vowels.

```
''.join([char if char not in "aeiou" else " " for char in 'mischtschenkoana']).split()

--> ['m', 'schtsch', 'nk', 'n']
```

The problem with zodiac is that none of the values in this list has length greater than one.

```
['z', 'd', 'c']
```

The if clause in your code for the case of len = 1 doesn't update the thing you return.

```
elif len(item) == 1:
    count += assigned_alphabet[item]
return max(count_list)
```

You update only count, not count_list. So you are returning an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I did not realize that after the:

```
elif len(item) == 1:
    count += assigned_alphabet[item]
```

I was not appending that to `count_list`